# How to add span tag in to webform element label?

Tags: theming, hooks, webforms, forms

I am trying to style my webform checkboxes and radio buttons differently. For this reason I want to insert span element in to the label and use it instead of original checkboxes.

Found this module : https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_optionsmarkup , but non of the listed options appear in my webform field settings.

Does any body know good solution to accomplish this ?